# Margin problems in CSS .... very stuck

Tags: css, html

When I add the unordered list in the header for the navigation, it pops the header down and knocks out the text that is floated right. If I remove it, all is well. Any ideas? I have been racking my head on this one... perhaps more sleep.

http://jsfiddle.net/YVmTB/2/

Also Ideally I would like the navigation to be horizontal... but i'm not quite there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/YVmTB/10/

added the 2 extra stylings to the end of the css

```
nav {
    float: left;   
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: This answer was posted 2 hours ago and the link is already dead. Please include your solution in the answer please.

Comment: @Meghan this was actually added 7 years ago. I updated the answer with an updated link and code though.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a simple CSS solutions.

Just add this line to your CSS:

```
nav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I added this to your CSS and it seems to look like you might want it.

```
nav>ul, nav>ul>li{
    float: left;
}

nav>ul>li{
    margin: 0 .5em;
}
```

Of course, an example of how it should look would be nice, but maybe this will help.

Comment: An explanation for this downvote would be nice.  The sample CSS posted does exactly what the OP wants it to do.